# JPA NamedQuery without table in database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have two tables in my database: packet_type and unit. 
I've created something-like-entity class PacketTypeExt to fetch joined data from both tables.
I have simple namedquery:

```
@NamedQuery(name="PacketTypeExt.findAll", query="select p.price, p.unit_amount as unitAmount, u.title as unitTitle from packet_type p join unit u on (p.idunit = u.idunit)")
```

I also have such fields in this class:

```
private int idpackettype;
private float price;
private int unitAmount;
private String unitTitle;
```

I don't wanna create another table or view to store joined data, so I did not placed "Entity" annotation. After running the webpage I've got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found: PacketTypeExt.findAll
```

What's the fastest and the least complicated way to fetch such a data successfully ?

Comment: A NamedQuery is supposed to use an entity name in the JPQL, yet yours uses the table name (unless you set the JPA metadata for the class to have entity name as packet_type. Also the message says that the QUERY is not found, not the TABLE.

Comment: Ok then, after adding annotation @Entity(name="packet_type") I get about 5 new errors in eclipse about incorrectness of the query...

-The state field path 'p.unit_amount' cannot be resolved to a   valid type.
- The abstract schema type 'unit' is unknown.
- The state field path 'u.title' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
- The state field path 'u.idunit' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

There is no really simple recipe to get columns from two tables??

Comment: Look, if you want to use a NamedQuery your query has to be JPQL. If you want to use a NamedNativeQuery then your query is SQL.

Comment: Well that's the answer I was looking for :) Thanks for your help and your patience!